# jetty plugin for ant : How to define a jvmarg like javaagent?

Tags: jvm-arguments, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm running an ant jetty task and i want to provide several jvmargs associated to jetty process : 
-Xmx
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port
-javaagent
-...

Can't find any option available besides ANT_OPTS..

Answer (score 0):

See this example: 
   http://ptrthomas.wordpress.com/2006/10/10/how-to-start-and-stop-jetty-from-ant/